# Marquee text appears in multiple lines

Tags: html, marquee

I have the following code:

```
<marquee><p>{a long text}</p></marquee>
```

The text within the marquee appears in multiple lines in webkit browsers. How do I force it to appear in one line? removing the `<p>` tag solves the problem but I want to know if there is a way rather than removing the `<p>` tag.

Comment: What happens when you move the <marquee></marquee> inside the <p></p>?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
marquee p
{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">
    Welcome! Feel free to surf on our website. 
    <span style="margin-left:1in;"></span> 
    This makes it appear as two marquees in 1 line
</marquee>
```

Comment: Welcome! Please add some explanation along with the suggested code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete `code` to understand **Marquee Texts on the same line**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Marquee Text on the same line</title>
    <style type="text/css"> 
    marquee span { 
    margin-right: 100%; 
    } 
    marquee p { 
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin-right: 1000px; 
    } 
</style> 
</head>
<body>
  <marquee scrollamount="10"><b>Hello, I am a StackOverflow user.<span> </span> And I Code the Web.</b></marquee> 
</body>
</html>
```

[Click here](https://output.jsbin.com/lekare) to get the live example of above code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code piece below in Django and it works well.

```
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <marquee width="100%" direction="left" height="30px" scrollamount="8">
            <p style="text-align: center;">
                {%for message in message_obj%}
                {{message.message}}&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                {%endfor%} 
            </p>
        </marquee>
    </div>
```